# can a domain in 3-dim noncompact manifold with Rc> 0 imbed into a 3-dim compact manifold with Rc> 0?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I do not know any example yet.

Comment: You're not assuming that the metric is complete? Otherwise, this was resolved by Schoen-Yau:
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=645740

Comment: If the metric is not complete, is not a spherical ball (as a domain of a bigger spherical ball) a counterexample?

Comment: Any connected noncompact manifold admits a noncomplete metric with Ric>0 (a result of Gromov). So if you know a 3-manifold which is not homeomorphic to a domain in a spherical form then you are done.

Comment: I should be more precise:
Can any bounded domain in 3-dim noncompact manifold with Rc> 0 be ISOMETRICALLY imbedded into a 3-dim compact manifold with Rc> 0? We assume the bounded domain has inherited metric from 3-dim noncompact manifold's metric, and the metric on noncompact manifold is complete.



Comment: Hi, guoyi, 
Do you mean that you want to close up a 3D manifold with boundary? It seems to be a question related to "prescribing Ricci curvature".

Comment: Yes, Chih-Wei, I wonder whether any bounded part of noncompact 3D manifold with positive Ricci can be closed up to a compact 3D compact manifold with positive Ricci, but its original metric is unchanged.
I did not find such example yet. It has application in Ricci flow of 3D manifolds.